# Dynamic display of table based on values in combobox using MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have two tables in MySQL db namely `vendor` and `menu`.

```
vendor table
vendor_id(Primary)   vendor_name

menu table
menu_id(Primary)     menu_details    cost     vendor_id(Foreign)
```

I need to create a combo box which fetches `vendor_name` instances from the MySQL db dynamically. On selection of `vendor_name` from the combo box, menu table(HTML and table should be in editable mode) should be displayed from the MySQL database. I am new to MySQL and PHP. So please help me to deal with this criteria.

Below is the code that I'm working on:

```
<html><body>
<select name="vendor" id="vendor">
<option value="Choose">Choose</option>
<?php $conn = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
if (!$con) { die('Could not connect: ' . Mysql_error()); }
mysql_select_db('project',$conn);
$query = "select vendor_id,vendor_name from vendor";
$result = mysql_query($query,$conn);
while($fetch= mysql_fetch_array($query)){
echo "<option>".$row[1]."</option>";
}?>
</select>
</body></html>
```

Comment: You need to show us (the stackoverflow people) that you have tried, put effort into making your code work. WHERE is the CODE?

Comment: Here is some documentation on using mysql with php:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: for dynamic display of combo box fetching values from the mysql db,I've  written the following code.But im not able to get the values in the combo box.

Comment: what you need is not hard to find in web tutorials

Comment: <html>
<body>
<select name="vendor" id="vendor">
          <option value="Choose">Choose</option>
         <?php 
   $conn = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
   if (!$con)
   {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }
    mysql_select_db('project',$conn);

    $query = "select vendor_id,vendor_name from vendor";

    $result = mysql_query($query,$conn);
                while($fetch= mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
                {  
   
         echo "<option>".$row[1]."</option>";
          
        }
              ?>   
</select>
</body>
</html>

Comment: `if (!$conn)` and `mysql_select_db('project',$conn) or die(mysql_error());`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood You correctly then this should do the thing that you're after. It displays the combobox from `vendor` table and if you change the selection, it reloads the page and shows the menu that corresponds to the vendor_id in the `menu` table.

```
<html>
<body>
<?php 
// connecting to the server
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die('Could not connect: ' . Mysql_error());
// selecting the database
mysql_select_db('project',$conn) or die("db error: ".mysql_error());
// is menu_id set?
if (isset($_GET['menu']) && intval($_GET['menu'])>0) {
    // if yes, then query the menu items
    $query = "select menu_id, menu_details, cost, vendor_id from menu where vendor_id=".intval($_GET['menu']);
    $result = mysql_query($query, $conn) or die("SQL error: ".mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        // print the menu items
        print_r($row);
    }
}
// select the vendor combobox
$query = "select vendor_id,vendor_name from vendor";
$result = mysql_query($query,$conn);

// If the vendor selection has changed then reload the page
?>
<select name="vendor" id="vendor" onchange="document.location='index.php?menu='+this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
<option value="Choose">Choose</option>
<?php
// loop through the results
while($fetch= mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    echo "<option value=\"".$row['vendor_id']."\">".$row['vendor_name']."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

the assumption is that the file is named `index.php`. (look at the select `onchange=""` filename. You'd need to change it if You have a different filename.